# Check for file duplication and remove

Tags: linux, bash

Basically what I'm looking to do is remove duplicated files and directories which exist among 2 particular locations. What I would like to do is create a script which will check the contents of directories "A" and "B" and in any cases where a directory that exists in "B" is also present in "A", remove from "B".

EXAMPLE:

/some/path/a

```
dir1
    file1.ext
    file2.ext
    file3.ext
dir2
    file1.ext
    file2.ext
    file3.ext
```

/some/path/b

```
dir1
    file1.ext
    file2.ext
    file3.ext
dir3
    file1.ext
    file2.ext
    file3.ext
```

In this example, the desired outcome would be to recognize that "dir1" exists in both places and then remove "dir1" and its contents from /some/path/b leaving everything else alone. I have played around in the terminal trying to achieve these results and looked online for answers but haven't found anything that fits this particular use case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
A=/some/path/a
B=/some/path/b

shopt -s nullglob

for dir in "$B"/*/; do
  if test -d "$A${dir#"$B"}"; then
    echo rm -r -- "$dir"
  fi
done
```

Remove `echo` if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `comm` from GNU coreutils:

```
a=some/path/a
b=some/path/b

mapfile -d '' dirs_to_del <                           \
  <(comm -z12                                         \
    <(shopt -s nullglob; cd "$a" && printf '%s\0' */) \
    <(shopt -s nullglob; cd "$b" && printf '%s\0' */))
cd "$b" && rm -rf -- "${dirs_to_del[@]}"
```

Drop the `echo` if output looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this

```
diff -r -s a b | grep -v "Only in" | awk '{print $4}' | xargs rm
```

Given the folder structure like this

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── dir1
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.txt
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   └── dir2
│       ├── file1.txt
│       ├── file2.txt
│       └── file3.txt
└── b
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   └── file2.txt
    └── dir3
        ├── file1.txt
        ├── file2.txt
        └── file3.txt
```

`diff -r -s a b` should show

```
Files a/dir1/file1.txt and b/dir1/file1.txt are identical
Files a/dir1/file2.txt and b/dir1/file2.txt are identical
Only in a/dir1: file3.txt
Only in a: dir2
Only in b: dir3
```

The `-s` is explained in `diff` as

```
       -s, --report-identical-files
              report when two files are the same
```

Comment: This works also, I only have to go back and remove the directories which contained the removed duplicated files, but considering my main issue was the extra storage taken up by those duplicated files, going back and removing some empty directories every so often is no problem. Thank you very much for the detailed response.